# how to delete all documents by predicate using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

For example i have a table:

```
| Col1       |        Col2 |
|:-----------|------------:|
|      1     |         one |
|      1     |         one |
|      1     |         one |
|      1     |         one |
|      2     |         two |
|      1     |         one |
```

And i want to delete all documents where `Col1 == 1` and get table:

```
| Col1       |        Col2 |
|:-----------|------------:|
|      2     |         two |
```

I trying some code but it doesn't work properly.

```
ElasticClient.DeleteByQuery<ElasticContent>(del => del
          .Index(ContentIndexName)
          .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
              .Must(m => m
                .Term(t => t
                  .Field(f => f.Col1)
                  .Value("1"))))));
```

How i can delete group of documents by specific query?

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work properly" ? No documents are deleted? Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Val, yes, no documents are deleted. I am using ES version 5.1.1, NEST 5.0.0.

Comment: Does the serialized query look as expected e.g. do the field names in the query match the field names in Elasticsearch? Do you need to wait for the delete by query to complete (`.WaitForCompletion()`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2.x version of elasticsearch you can use a plugin. The first link is why they removed DeleteByQuery from 2.x versions. The second link is how to install it and use it.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/delete-by-query-plugin-reason.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/delete-by-query-usage.html

If you are using version 5.x it has been added again and should be able to use it like normal. I would double check your version again.